# Why is $2^\omega = \alpha^\omega$ defined as the limit of finite ordinals ( i.e. $ = \omega$)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Okay my understanding so far is that:
We have ordinal exponentiation which I think is a normal function.. Now the sequence $ \lbrace n | n < \omega \rbrace$ is increasing. Let $f: \omega \to \omega, \alpha ^ \omega (\alpha \text{ is finite})$. Then  $\lim_{\beta < \omega} \alpha ^ \omega = \lim_{\beta < \omega} n = \omega$.

There's also this I've seen where $\alpha ^ \omega = \bigcup_{\beta < \omega} \alpha ^ \beta = \omega$.

I think that $\alpha ^ \omega = \bigcup_{\beta < \omega} \alpha ^ \beta $ comes from $\alpha^\omega$ with $\alpha < \omega$ being an increasing sequence with a unique limit. But why does this equal $\omega$

Comment: $\alpha^\beta$ is finite if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are, so $\omega$ is an upper bound.  But if $\alpha>1$ then $\alpha^\beta$ is increasing with $\beta$, so will exceed any finite ordinal with large enough $\beta$; for example $\alpha^\beta \ge \beta$.  This means $\omega$ is the least ordinal which is an upper bound and so the limit.

Comment: $2^\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}2^n$. This set is cofinal in $\omega$, and all members of it are natural numbers, so between them the powers of two contain all the natural numbers, i.e. the union is $\omega$